# "Could not find or load main class" при запуске программы

Tags: java

Пытаюсь выполнить обычный *Hello, World*, как это сказано в одном из мануалов.

```
class HelloWorld
{    
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");    
    }    
}
```

Запускаю в транслятор так:

```
javac C:\Java\HelloWorld.java
```

Все проходит успешно. По крайней мере, никаких сообщений о крахе не выводится.

Но когда уже хочу получить результат, запуская так:

```
java HelloWorld
```

То в консоли выводится ошибка:

> Java could not find the main class HelloWorld

Как его запустить, в чем проблема?

Вот полный лог происходящего в консоли:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin>javac C:\Java\HelloWorld.java
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin>java HelloWorld
>   Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin>

Comment: Перенеси HelloWorld.class в папку C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin

Comment: Если убрать из исходника строку package все заработает

Comment: @АртурЛомако: Не учите плохому. А вот если будет программа по-сложнее - что с ней делать? Надо на простых программах язык постигать.

Comment: @АртурЛомако: К слову, автор нигде не писал, что у него в исходнике вообще есть строка package.

Comment: Все способы перепробовал - ничего не работает. Как была ошибка Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld.class так и есть

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Пробуйте так:

```
java -classpath . HelloWorld
```

или так:

```
java -cp . HelloWorld
```

Иначе java не может найти скомпилированный класс.

Comment: странно, вроде удалил этот вопрос. Там я дей-но запускал `java` не из мною созданной директории java, в которой скомпилированный бинарник хранился.

Answer (score 6):

Герберт Шилдт в своей книге по JDK8 приводит простой но **Очень** полезный пример компиляции и запуска программы:

ПРИМЕР:

содержимое файла Book.java

```
package bookpack;

class Book {
    //....
}
```

этот файл **необходимо** поместить в каталог bookpack

Скомпилировать нужно так:

```
javac bookpack/Book.java
```

А выполнить так:

```
java bookpack.Book
```

*** ВНИМАНИЕ ***
Не забывайте, что для нормального выполнения указанных выше команд, текущим
должен быть каталог, являющийся **родительским** по отношению к каталогу bookpack.

*P.S. лично проверил - работает! Дерзайте! Да прибудет с вами сила! ;)*

Comment: *лично проверил - работает!* - даже без main(), и работает?

Comment: с таким main() как у человека задавшего вопрос - да, работает.

Comment: Действительно, работает. Только компилировал я просто находясь в каталоге с файлом.

Answer (score 3):

У меня был случай когда даже команда

```
java -classpath . HelloWorld
```

давала ошибку 
"Could not find or load main class"
решилось таким образом

```
java -classpath "jar_name" com.list_of_your_packages.launcher
```

То есть нужно было указать сам джарник в classpath, а потом указать полный путь к классу с main методом

Answer (score 2):

Для класса, лежащего в директории src и в пакете basic,

```
package basic;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("Hello from Main");

    }

}
```

у меня работает так

```
$ javac src/basic/Main.java
$ java -cp src basic.Main
Hello from Main
```

Comment: А basic - Это тоже директория?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть кому-нибудь пригодится. Нашел еще один вариант ответа, который помог мне:

Иногда полезно читать не только книжки, но и документацию.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

java команда не воспринимает ваше 
`e:\MyJava\example` как путь вообще.

Она считает что это имя класса. Пути задаются иначе. Это большая и сложная тема - classpath.

```
java -cp e:\MyJava\ example
```

Мы указываем искать классы в `e:\MyJava\` запустить класс `example`.

Comment: Попробуйте отформотировать ответ, он плохо читаем.

Answer (score 0):

Потратил не мало времени что бы решить этот вопрос, а решение таково. Нужно правильно прописывать переменные среды. Нужно в переменных среды указывать путь к `bin` и путь к `lib`. Про `lib` редко кто говорит. Если запускать из командной строки и путь к библиотекам не указан в переменных среды, то jvm не знает где их брать.  Win 10.
Например  `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\lib\`  и `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\`
Успехов!

Answer (score 0):

В переменных среды, где пишете в переменную CLASSPATH путь до JDK, перед путем поставьте ".;". У меня получилось `.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin` Точка означает текущий каталог. После редактирования не забудьте перезагрузить Windows.

Comment: Перезагружать кажется не обязательно,  достаточно открыть новое окно командного интерпретатора. Проверьте, дополните ответ, если оно так.

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решается, если изменить строку запуска

вместо команды javac C:\Java\HelloWorld.java
запускать так  javac C:\Java\HelloWorld

С удалением расширения файла *.java мэйн класс обнаруживается. Программа запускается. Почему именно так, я не стал разбираться.

Answer (score -2):

- Перейди в нужный каталог с помощью консольной команды **cd**;
- Так же можно добавить нужный путь в переменную среды **CLASSPATH**;
- Самый простой способ это вызвать **CMD** из **TotalCommander**, перейдя в нужный катало.