# При запуске скомпилированного файла ошибка Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven

Я написал в IDE (использую Intellij IDEA, Windows 10) код, работающий с PostgreSQL. При помощи Maven указал в pom.xml зависимость - драйвер JDBC. В IDE код работает правильно, проблемы начинаются после компиляции.

У меня есть папка .m2 с репозиторием Maven и папка target со скомпилированным файлом. Переменные среды (пути к JDK) настроены.

Если я запускаю при помощи консоли мой файл командой java package.Importer, то получаю ошибку подключения драйвера (стоп, а какой тогда смысл в Maven и зачем я прописывал dependency?).

Если я использую команду java -cp [путь к драйверу] package.Importer, то получаю ошибку:

> Could not find or load main class

Если я пытаюсь прописать два пути через [путь к драйверу];[путь к папке classes в папке target] то в консоли у меня вообще вылетает справка по командам java.

То есть либо я прописываю classpath к драйверу JDBC, но java не находит мой файл с методом main, либо я запускаю консоль из папки classes, запускаю мой файл, но он не видит JDBC.

Comment: поставьте у postgres зависимости `<scope>runtime</scope>`

Comment: `java -cp <путь к классу>;<путь к драверу> <имя класса>`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка invoking method при запуске jar](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/856878/204271)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["Could not find or load main class" при запуске программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148287/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1):

В моём случае нужно было указать два пути. Один из путей к папке, которая является корневой для пакета (в моём случае это папка classes, в которой находится папка com\dk\smartsoft\Importer.class), другой путь к папке, где лежит подключаемая библиотека. Нельзя просто указать только путь к папке с библиотеками и оставить путь к пакету по умолчанию.

```
java -cp "D:\Java\Libs\*;D:\Java\testproject\target\classes" com.dk.smartsoft.Importer
```