# Создание рабочего java-класса в репозитории Git'a

Tags: java

Имеется git репа. 
Выглядит так:

```
ivanov_vasya
   -homework1
       -(какие-то файлы, диаграммы и прочее, написанное ручками в блокноте)
   -homework2
       -(тут нужен рабочий класс)
```

Как можно заметить в одной из папок нужен рабочий класс с main'ом, чтобы вывести сообщение.

Просто открыв проект в Intellij IDEA, создав файл `className.java` и описав класс `className` с методом `main()` результата не дал, это просто текст.

Как правильно создать рабочий класс в этой папке и запустить?

UPD. Пометил `homework2` как `source root`, а также добавил папку для вывода. 
Теперь класс можно запустить, но выдаёт ошибку типа

`Error: Could not find or load main class className`

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: className`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Could not find or load main class" при запуске программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148287/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Comment: package указал?