# java настройка окружения, работа в командной строке

Tags: java, командная-строка

Зараннее благодарю за помощь.
Готовлюсь к сертификации по java, хочу настроить компиляцию java кода в командной строку.
Переменная среды %JAVA_HOME% настроена
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Path добавлена

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Java установлена

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Байткод класса создается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почему-то не компилируется. Уже чего-то только не делала

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В классе ошибок нет, в idea он компилируется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я сделала не так? Может, кто-то заметил ошибку.

С именем пакета не проходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас все правильно настроено и правильно компилируется, просто вы неправильно вызываете программу. Это особенности того, как java ищет пути до классов. Если бы не было package, то все либо отработало нормально, либо отработало через `> java -cp . Test`. Можете удалить package и проверить. А вот как правильно указывать пути CLASSPATH до ресурсов в случае наличия package пути я честно сходу не скажу.

Comment: Посмотрите тут, может что-то полезное будет: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J9c_PackageClasspath.html

Comment: Спасибо. Но и без пакета и с командой >java -cp .Test тоже не работает. Думаю проблемы с Windows 10, в нём всё не так работает.

Comment: я думаю, это всё-таки что-то windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Нужно запускать с полным именем класса, включая package:

```
C:\Oca>java host.igor.Test
```

Находиться нужно в папке `Oca`, чтобы иерархия package соответствовала иерархии папок.

Если не указан package, должно запускаться из той же папки, где class файл.
Попробуйте выполнить в командной строке в какой-нибудь пустой папке:

```
echo public class Main {public static void main(String[] args) {System.out.println(args[0]);}} > Main.java
javac Main.java
java Main hello
```

Comment: Это не помогает C:\Oca>java host.igor.Test
Error: Could not find or load main class host.igor.Test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: host.igor.Test

Comment: Можете вывод `C:\Oca>tree /f C:\Oca\host` показать?

Comment: C:\Oca>tree /f C:\Oca\host
Структура папок тома Acer
Серийный номер тома: 40FE-BBAD
C:\OCA\HOST
└───igor
        Test.class
        Test.java

Comment: Файлы вроде на месте. Сложно понять, что у вас на компьютере происходит. Я обновил ответ, попробуйте с нуля через cmd сделать в пустой папке. У вас модификатор public у класса отсутствует, хотя это вроде в данной ситуации не должно влиять.

Comment: Всё те же ошибки

Comment: Main.java и Main.class создались, но при запуске не находит?

Comment: да, классы создались, но не находит

Comment: И так `java -cp . Main` не запускает? А переменную среды CLASSPATH вы не трогали? Непонятно :(

Comment: она тоже настроена C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin

Comment: C:\Users\AcerUser>echo %CLASSPATH%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin

Comment: В CLASSPATH у вас отсутствует текущая папка `.`, посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/953343/271740 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/865913/271740

Comment: Попробуйте CLASSPATH удалить из переменных среды и перезапустить компьютер.

Comment: тоже не помогло