# Error: Could not find or load main class Example Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, консоль

Ошибка при запуске:

```
PS C:\Users\Stas\IdeaProjects\project1> cd src\chapter1
PS C:\Users\Stas\IdeaProjects\project1\src\chapter1> javac Example.java
PS C:\Users\Stas\IdeaProjects\project1\src\chapter1> java Example
Error: Could not find or load main class Example
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Example
```

В переменную окружения CLASSPATH задала путь C:\Users\Stas\IdeaProjects
Если задавать classpath через консоль, тоже выводит ошибку:

```
PS C:\Users\Stas\IdeaProjects\project1\src\chapter1> java -cp . Example
Error: Could not find or load main class Example
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: chapter1/Example (wrong name: Example)
```

НО! Программа всё же запускается, если задать расширение файла:

```
PS C:\Users\Stas\IdeaProjects\project1\src\chapter1> java Example.java
Hello World!
```

Возможно, это в дальнейшем ничем не чревато, в таком случае, могу забыть об этой проблеме и дальше запускать тем путём, каким получается. Я только начала изучать программирование, поэтому не знаю, биться мне над этой ошибкой или пропустить.

Comment: не тратьте сейчас своё время, скачивайте ide и пишите там, когда освоитесь немного, запустите с консоли разок, для общего развития.

Comment: я там и пишу, в InteliJ IDEA

Comment: а в переменные среды java_home и pass прописаны? в CLASSPATH  надо писать писать путь к javac который в папке jdk\bin а не путь к файлу

Comment: да, в JAVA_HOME задала путь C:\Diana\Java\jdk-11.0.13 , в СLASSPATH добавила путь C:\Diana\Java\jdk-11.0.13\bin

Comment: в консоли вводили  javac -version?

Comment: да, выводит ответ: javac 11.0.13 . Насколько поняла из форума, так и должно быть

Comment: а вы через консоль в ide запускаете? а через кнопку run (shift+f10) пробывали?

Comment: так запускается

Comment: ну так и не партесь) ... возможно всё намного проще и у вас просто какаето мелкая ошибка с самом коде, пробуте тут посмотреть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148287/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-при-запуске-программы

Comment: ну в коде ошибки быть не может, это же HelloWorld) эту страницу уже читала, всё пробовала. ну хорошо, надеюсь, ничего страшного, спасибо

Comment: удачи в начинаниях

Comment: _____спасибо :)

Comment: может тут что поможет https://www.baeldung.com/java-could-not-find-load-main-class

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["Could not find or load main class" при запуске программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148287/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Comment: 1) приведите исходный код `Example.java`, вероятно следует указать название пакета при запуске из директории `src`: `/src> java -cp chapter1; chapter1.Example` 2) перед запуском проверьте, в какой директории оказались `.class` файлы после компиляции.